# newly inserted data doesn't display in the combobox control

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I just inserted data into my sql database. Actually, I want to retrieve it automatically into 
my combobox. But it does display the old value. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to rebind your combobox after the insert.

The data is disconnected from the controls.